# Logging in ASP.NET Core, what should replace System.Diagnostics.EventLog

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core

When targeting `dnxcore50` I don't seem to get trusty old EventLog, for good reason since it is only on Windows.

```
"The type or namespace name 'EventLog' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics'"
```

The *.NET Portability Report* has no recommendations, is there a new recommended logging strategy for dot net core?